# How can I set the position of an element relative to the bottom or right side using svg.js?

Tags: svg.js

I need to have some text on the bottom of a svg. I want the text 0px from the bottom. I couldn't find a solution in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
elm.y(height - elm.bbox().height);
```

Comment: You can also go `text.attr(y, draw.height())`. This will move the baseline of the text to the bottom. Please note that it can happen that stuff below the baseline is not visible then